# Show location in sharepoint base on lync location

Tags: sharepoint, lync

Is there a way to set up a column that would allow SharePoint to use Lync location.  Such as if Lync shows you at 1400 building, SharePoint can show you at that same location.  Then if you move, that location would be updated as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The Location property is available only on Lync. I'm not aware of any possibility of mapping with Active Directory fields and, consequently, syncing in SharePoint.
Further, as you can imagine this property value can change frequently. In case you'd be able to it map with SharePoint User Profiles, you'd be always subject to user profile synchronization schedule to have this property updated.

A possibility would be to create a visual component in SharePoint that, communicating directly with Lync via REST APIs (UCWA), retrieves this information directly from Lync, and displays this in your SharePoint pages.

The best starting point for information about Lync 2013 UCWA is: http://ucwa.lync.com

Comment: Correct.  I know that lycn should integrate with SharePoint already because of how it uses Presence and how we can see if a person is away/busy/available.  So can SharePoint pull more information from lync or is it just limited to status?

Comment: No it isn't possible to display directly the Location information using the standard templates provided.
This post shows you the possibilities offered by standard templates (in SP2013): http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/add-presence-to-sharepoint-search-results/
They are indeed limited to Display Name, Picture, and Presence Status